# Create broken axis in graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis

I wrote the following code to make a graph:

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Grafiek.xlsx')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('Datum', 'Percentage', data=data)


fmt_half_year = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(fmt_half_year)


fmt_month = mdates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(fmt_month)


ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))


ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

ax.grid(True)


plt.xlabel('Datum')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.title('Percentage Trained')

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

It shows me the following graph
[image]

I want to make a broken axis from 2015-03 to 2018-03. Anyone a idea how to write the right code?

Thanks!

Comment: @mcsoini I want to have a broken axis on the x-axis instead of the y-axis, and because off I have to deal with dates I don't know how to set up de lim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing heavily from the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html), we can modify it slightly to move to a broken x axis instead of y axis.

The main changes from that example to here:

- change to `sharey=True`
- turn off left/right spines instead of bottom/top
- change position/angle of diagonal lines to show broken axes
- change proportion of two axes since the left axes spans a shorter range

Note for the last point, here I have made them a 1:10 ratio, because I have made the second axes span 40 months, and the first axes space 4 months. You will likely want a slightly different ratio, so will need to adjust the `xlim` for each axes accordingly, and also the `width_ratios` parameter.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

drange = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=78, freq='M')
data = pd.DataFrame({'Datum': drange, 'Percentage': np.random.randn(len(drange))}) 

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': (1, 10)})
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)

ax1.plot('Datum', 'Percentage', data=data)
ax2.plot('Datum', 'Percentage', data=data)

fmt_half_year1 = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
fmt_half_year2 = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(fmt_half_year1)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(fmt_half_year2)

fmt_month1 = mdates.MonthLocator()
fmt_month2 = mdates.MonthLocator()
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(fmt_month1)
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(fmt_month2)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

ax1.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax2.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

ax1.grid(True)
ax2.grid(True)

# hide the spines between ax1 and ax2
ax1.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.left.set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.tick_params(labelright=False)  # don't put tick labels at the top
ax1.xaxis.tick_bottom()

datemin1 = np.datetime64(data['Datum'][0], 'M')
datemax1 = np.datetime64(data['Datum'][4], 'M')
ax1.set_xlim(datemin1, datemax1)

datemin2 = np.datetime64(data['Datum'][37], 'M')
datemax2 = np.datetime64(data['Datum'][77], 'M')
ax2.set_xlim(datemin2, datemax2)


fig.text(s='Datum', x=0.5, y=0.05)
ax1.set_ylabel('Percentage')
fig.suptitle('Percentage Trained')

fig.autofmt_xdate()

d = 2.  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax1.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 0], [0, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: One other question: fmt_half_year1 = mdates.MonthLocator(interval=6) here I want to have 2 dates which I can choose  by myself. For example 2015-01 and 2018-03. How can I fix that?