# Matplotlib multiple broken axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to make a plot with 2 breaks in the x-axis. I can produce one break following the matplotlib

```
days = list(range(0,500))
values = list(np.random.randint(low = 10,high=100,size=len(days)))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

f,(ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True, facecolor='w')

ax.plot(days, values)
ax2.plot(days, values)

ax.set_xlim(0,100)  # x-axis range limited to 0 - 100 
ax2.set_xlim(250, 300)  # x-axis range limited to 250 - 300

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.tick_params(labelright='off')

d = .015 # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((1-d,1+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)
ax.plot((1-d,1+d),(1-d,1+d), **kwargs)

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (1-d,1+d), **kwargs)
ax2.plot((-d,+d), (-d,+d), **kwargs)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, how can I modify this to have another break to have an `ax3` between 400 and 500? Additionally, how can I scale the x-axis length to be reflective of the length of the interval? In the above I would ideally like the right side reduced as it is half the interval.

I have tried using the brokenaxes which looks like it would meet the criteria automatically scaling and allowing multiple breaks refer to here e.g. https://test-brokenaxes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_usage.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-usage-py

However, when running that code I get

```
AttributeError: 'SubplotSpec' object has no attribute 'is_last_row'
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `is_last_row` became deprecated in 3.4, so I assume `broken axes` hasn't been updated to account for that. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase.html#matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase.is_last_row

Comment: And possibly related: I showed in this answer how you could make a broken axes plot with difference sized x-axis depending on the range: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67718650/create-broken-axis-in-graph/67719343#67719343

Comment: Thanks, looks definitely along the lines I need. Could you add another break to what you presented as there is left and right position, can you add a centre? @tmdavison

Comment: Yes, I've just added an answer showing how to add a central axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the width of the different subplots using the `gridspec_kw` argument to `plt.subplots`. In there, we define the `width_ratios`. In this case, you have the first and third subplots twice as wide as the middle one, so we can use `(2,1,2)` for the ratios.

We then need to make sure we turn off the correct spines: so for the left axes (`ax1`), we turn off the right spine. In the middle (`ax2`) we turn off both left and right, and on the right axes (`ax3`), we just turn off the left spine.

On the right axes, I move the y-axis ticks to the right hand side using `ax3.yaxis.tick_right()`

In the middle axes, I hide the ticks with `ax2.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)` --- note we can't just use something like `ax2.set_yticks([])` here because that would affect the other axes, since we use `sharey=True`.

I've then taken the code to draw the diagonal lines from my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67718650/create-broken-axis-in-graph/67719343#67719343), and added extra lines for the second break in the x axis.

All together, that looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

days = list(range(0,500))
values = list(np.random.randint(low = 10,high=100,size=len(days)))

# use width_ratios to define the width of each subplot
# depending on the range we want to plot
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, facecolor='w',
                                  gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': (2, 1, 2)})

ax1.plot(days, values)
ax2.plot(days, values)
ax3.plot(days, values)

ax1.set_xlim(0,100)  # x-axis range limited to 0 - 100 
ax2.set_xlim(250, 300)  # x-axis range limited to 250 - 300
ax3.set_xlim(400, 500)  # x-axis range limited to 400 - 500

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

# Move right hand axes ticks to right hand side
ax3.yaxis.tick_right()

# Turn off ticks on middle axes; so we don't affect the other
# axes ticks, let's just set the length to 0 here
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', length=0)

# Draw the diagonal lines to show broken axes
d = 2.  # proportion of vertical to horizontal extent of the slanted line
kwargs = dict(marker=[(-1, -d), (1, d)], markersize=12,
              linestyle="none", color='k', mec='k', mew=1, clip_on=False)
ax1.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], transform=ax1.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([0, 0], [0, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax2.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], transform=ax2.transAxes, **kwargs)
ax3.plot([0, 0], [0, 1], transform=ax3.transAxes, **kwargs)

plt.savefig('2brokenaxes.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just as I need!

Comment: @tmdavidson is it possible to include two of the above into a single output figure?

Comment: sure, you would just need to change to `plt.subplots(2, 3,...)` if you want them on top of each other or `plt.subplots(1, 6, ...)` if you want them next to each other. Then catch all 6 axes returned from subplots, and just repeat the logic above for the second set of 3